# What NDK standalone toolchain options provide the widest device compatibility?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I need to compile a JNI library using the NDK standalone toolchain for Android and would like to provide support for as many devices as possible. It appears I need to build for x86, Arm hard float, Arm soft float, and MIPS devices. What is not clear is what combination of options for these toolchains in terms of version and arch support will work on as many devices as possible. Does anyone have any suggestions on this?